# Multiline ruleorder in Snakemake

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 3 rules and their names are somewhat long. When using `ruleorder`, the line goes over my desired 80 character limit. Is it possible break up the `ruleorder` into multiple lines in such a way that the behaviour is *exactly* the same as if I wrote it all in one line?

Example:

```py
ruleorder: long_rule_1 > long_rule_2 > long_rule_3
```

I would like to reformat it into something like this:

```py
ruleorder: (
    long_rule_1 
    > long_rule_2 
    > long_rule_3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at ways to do this, I believe the best way is pretty simple:

```
ruleorder:
    long_rule_1
    > long_rule_2
    > long_rule_3
```

The other answers are good too, but this is the one that I'm using

Answer (score 4):

To break the long lines it's possible to use `\` as line continuation:

```py
# Snakefile
rule all:
    input: '1.txt'

for k in list("abcde"):
    rule:
        name: k
        output: '1.txt'

ruleorder: a > b > c > \
        d > e
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from @SultanOrazbayev I would add that the syntax below also works:

```py
ruleorder: long_rule_1 > long_rule_2
ruleorder: long_rule_2 > long_rule_3
```

That will work in your simple case, but is not fully equivalent to the ruleorder with all three rules in one line. Snakemake creates a list of ruleorders, and applies them one by one. Strictly speaking, there is a difference in applying one ruleorder of three rules and two ruleorders two rules each. This way you can even introduce cycles which is impossible in one line, so I would prefer a single ruleorder whenever possible.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore (it used to work in older snakemake versions, but when I try this syntax now I get an error)... could also be a bug (I'm using 7.20.0).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev, what kind of *syntax* error do you get? This syntax is fully valid, aren't you disputing the syntax from the response of yippingAppa?